# Convertir minúsculas a mayúsculas no funciona bien con upper

Tags: python

Espero puedan ayudarme con esto, llevo hora tratando de conseguir que funcione si tener resultados.

Tengo el siguiente código python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
frase = 'La canción de la piña'
print frase.upper()
```

Al momento de hacer el print, me arroja "LA CANCIóN DE LA PIñA" y no "LA CANCIÓN DE LA PIÑA" ¿Alguna persona sabe como puedo resolver esto?

Tampoco funciona haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
frase = u"La canción de la piña"
frase = frase.encode('utf-8').upper()
print frase
```

Gracias

Comment: El tratamiento de unicode es diferente en Python 2/3. Estás usando Python 2 ?

Answer (score 3):

Si trabajas con strings en `utf-8` necesitas decodificar la cadena para poder trabajar con ella:

```
frase = 'La canción de la piña'
print frase.decode('utf-8').upper()
```

Mientras que si trabajas con strings en `unicode` no es necesario decodificarla:

```
frase = u'La canción de la piña'
print frase.upper()
```

En ambos casos, se devuelve el string convertido correctamente:

```
LA CANCIÓN DE LA PIÑA
```

Saludos.

Comment: Y que sucede cuando la consola no muestra el caracter correctamente?

Comment: @NaCl La salida de la consola depende del OS, en Windows : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878972/windows-cmd-encoding-change-causes-python-crash/3259271 Lo más simple y sano (al menos que realmente necesites interactuar con la salida de la consola) es tirar la salida a un archivo

Comment: Gracias @leonboy tenía esa duda, probare a tirar la salida a un archivo.